# java localstack lambada - how to run lambada and see logs

Tags: aws-java-sdk, localstack

I am trying to run lambada using localStack and to see the log ...

so thee running class looks like :

```
        public class LambdaLoader implements RequestHandler<Object, String> {
      @Override
      public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
          LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        logger.log("\"started\"");
            return "Complete";
      }
```

I am running it

```
public class LambdaLoaderIT {

  @Test
  void handleRequest() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration =
      new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
        "http://localhost:4566", Regions.US_EAST_1.getName());
    AWSLambda lambdaClient = createLambdaClient(endpointConfiguration);

    createLambda(lambdaClient);

  }

  private AWSLambda createLambdaClient(
    AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration) {
    return AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
      .withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfiguration)
      .withCredentials(
        new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
          new BasicAWSCredentials("dummyAccessKey", "dummySecretKey")))
      .build();
  }

  private void createLambda(AWSLambda clientLambda) throws IOException {
    CreateFunctionRequest functionRequest = new CreateFunctionRequest();
    functionRequest.setHandler("com.ssp.coreTeam.LambdaLoader::handleRequest");
    functionRequest.setFunctionName("handleRequest");
    functionRequest.setTimeout(900);
    functionRequest.setRuntime("java11");
    functionRequest.setRole("arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:handleRequest");

    FunctionCode code = new FunctionCode();
    File file = new File("target/my-lambda-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] bytes = IoUtils.toByteArray(fileInputStream);
    code.setZipFile(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));
    functionRequest.setCode(code);
    Environment environment = new Environment();
    environment.setVariables(Map.of("LAMBDA_ENV","dev"));
    functionRequest.setEnvironment(environment);
    CreateFunctionResult function = clientLambda.createFunction(functionRequest);
    System.out.println(function);
  }
```

in addition, this is how I have configured lambada in the docker-compose file (notice LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=local ):

```
  localstack:
    image: 'localstack/localstack'
    ports:
      - '4566:4566'
    environment:
      - SERVICES=lambda,ssm
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR- }
      - PORT_WEB_UI=${PORT_WEB_UI- }
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=local
      - KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY=${KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - HOST_TMP_FOLDER=${TMPDIR}
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

How can I see the logs and what happened there?

Answer (score -1):

You've already set the `DEBUG` to `1`, so the logs are there.

To read them, use the [standard Docker Compose facilities for logs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/logs/). In your case it should be something like:

```sh
docker-compose logs localstack
```

---

I would also recommend you to use a small library to inject AWS clients in your tests, named [`aws-junit5`](https://github.com/madhead/aws-junit5). It would greatly simplify your tests. It supports Lambda clients for both AWS Java SDK 1.x and 2.x. [The usage](https://madhead.github.io/aws-junit5/asciidoc/#_basic_usage) is pretty straightforward:

```java
@ExtendWith(Lambda.class)
class AmazonDynamoDBInjectionTest {
    @AWSClient(endpoint = Endpoint.class) // Endpoint configuration
    private AWSLambda client;

    @Test
    void test() {
        CreateFunctionRequest functionRequest = new CreateFunctionRequest();
        
        functionRequest.setHandler("com.ssp.coreTeam.LambdaLoader::handleRequest");
        functionRequest.setFunctionName("handleRequest");
        functionRequest.setTimeout(900);
        functionRequest.setRuntime("java11");
        functionRequest.setRole("arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:handleRequest");

        FunctionCode code = new FunctionCode();
        File file = new File("target/my-lambda-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] bytes = IoUtils.toByteArray(fileInputStream);

        code.setZipFile(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));
        functionRequest.setCode(code);

        Environment environment = new Environment();

        environment.setVariables(Map.of("LAMBDA_ENV","dev"));
        functionRequest.setEnvironment(environment);

        // Just use client here, it will be auto-injected!
        CreateFunctionResult function = client.createFunction(functionRequest);

        // Rest of your test
        System.out.println(function);
    }
}
```

There is even [an example of CI/CD with GitHub](https://madhead.github.io/aws-junit5/asciidoc/#_bonus_ci_with_github), which is very similar to what you're doing.